# Java `NumberFormat` assumes incorrect number type

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, number-formatting

For instance:

```java
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.newInstace();
Number number = nf.parse("0.0");
```

`number` is resolved as `java.lang.Integer` at run-time, even though it's clear that the value is `Double`.
Most of the time it's not a problem since the value is wrapped in a `Number` anyway, but the issue is that `Number` does not implement `Comparable`, and I have to resort to casting it.

Is there a class that assumes `"0.0"`-like strings to represent a `Double`?

Comment: If the numbers you want to parse are doubles, why not parse them as Double: `Double.parseDouble(numberAsString)`

Answer (score 1):

Numberformat is aware of the way numbers are written in your region. Eg in Italy you have "," as decimal point. So:

```
     NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
     Number number = nf.parse("0,1");
     System.err.println(number);
```

> 0.1

While if you used a "." which is just used to create groups (eg thousands) you will get 1 as result(which is correct as 01 is 1):

```
     NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
     Number number = nf.parse("0.1");
     System.err.println(number);
```

> 1

Now with an english locale it is the exact opposite:

```
        NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Number number = nf.parse("0.1");
        System.err.println(number);
```

> 0.1

And finally english with a ",":

```
        NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Number number = nf.parse("0,1");
        System.err.println(number);
```

> 1

Someone argued about trailing 0's. So:

```
   NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
   double d = nf.parse("17").doubleValue();
   double d2 = nf.parse("17.000").doubleValue();
```

Both d and d2 will have the same value. This is the exact same behavior as if I assigned the variables in code.

```
   double d = 17;
   double d2 = 17.000;
```

Both variables will contain the same number. In both cases without  loss of precision.

Also a comparison will correctly return true:

```
   boolean test = nf.parse("17") == nf.parse("17.000");
   System.err.print( test );
```

> true

Which is the same behavior as in code:

```
   boolean test = 17 == 17.000;
   System.err.print( test );
```

> true

Finaly the returntype of NumberFormat is a "Number". It parses a number as what it is: a Number. So this is neither a Double nor a Long(like an Animal is not a Dog nor a Cat, even if a Dog is an Animal  ).

If you need reliably a double you just use number.doubleValue() which gives you reliably the required type.